# CMD command to open all files in a subdirectory?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Let’s say I navigate to a certain folder such as `Z:\users\me\example` in command prompt and I’d like to open multiple files simultaneously. I don’t know the exact number of files (I know for sure it won’t crash the system, as the max would be 10 files), and the file extension varies from .pdf, to .jpg, to .docx.

Is there a command(s) that will open all files in said directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FOR %F IN (*.*) DO START %F
```

should do the trick, provided that all of the files have extensions that are associated with applications in the registry.

*Haroldo and harrymc both bring up a good point about filenames having spaces; to handle that case, one should use*

```
FOR %F IN (*.*) DO START "" "%F"
```

*instead*.

Comment: How would you tweak the command to accept file names with spaces in them? Such as ‘Yukis Birthday Photo.jpg’?

Comment: This solution won't work if the file name has whitespaces.

Comment: Use `start "%F"`.

Comment: @harrymc - Not quite; it would be `START "" "%F"`. If the first parameter to START is a quoted string, it interprets it as the title of the window to open. Which, IMO, is just plain ***stupid***; the title should be an optional parameter with a required switch preceding it, e.g., `/T`.